# Summarize if-statement and read if conditions from another object like String[] (Dynamic If)

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, dynamic, properties-file

I have a complex object (the name of that object is "input") that has a lot of fields, and I want check null each fields. Currently, I have below unclean code:

```java
if ((input.getAction().isEmpty() || input.getAction().isBlank()) ||
        (input.getSubAction().isEmpty() || input.getSubAction().isBlank()) ||
        (input.getLob().isEmpty() || input.getLob().isBlank()) ||
        (input.getBusinessType().isEmpty() || input.getBusinessType().isBlank()) || ...)
```

As you can see I have more condition checks.

First: I want summarize this code. I know I could create a simple method for each item checking, and also could use `java.util.Objects.isNull` and `object == null`. If you have better ways, I'd like to know them.

Second: I want read if-conditions parameters from another object like `String[]`, which I read this object, for example from application.properties. Similarly, I want to create a *dynamic if-statement*. See below pseudocode:

```java
String[] params = {"action" , "subAction" , "lob", ...};
if(input."params[0]".isEmpty() || input."params[1]".isEmpty() || ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons-beanutils has a class which will let you generalize properties like this.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#getProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-

Basically it's s a wrapper around reflection, so you would need only supply a string with the property name, then check the returned value for null and empty.

```
for (String prop : properties) {
    String propValue = BeanUtils.getProperty(object, prop);
    if (propValue == null || propValue != null) throw new Exception("Something");
}
```

Alternately, Hibernate Validator will allow you to use annotations on your beans to specify validation logic in a more flexible way.

Comment: Thanks @SplinterReality